# $L^p$ estimate for elliptic operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the elliptic operator $Lu=a_{ij}\partial_{ij}u+b_iu+cu$, in bounded domain ,we have the estimate $\|u\|_{H^2}\leq\|Lu\|_{L^2}+\|u\|_{L^2}$ for sufficiently smooth coefficient. Does such result hold for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

---

I turn to the famous paper [Agmon-Douglis-Nirenberg](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/cpa.3160120405), but couldn't find the result.